# Discord bot closing after I close my Python shell

Tags: python, discord.py

So I wrote a Discord bot in Python and it worked. But, when I close my Python shell (where I run my code) the bot stops working. Is there anything I can do so my bot keeps working no matter if the shell is closed or not? Just in case if you need the code, here it is

```
import os
import random
import datetime
import discord

bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.id == bot.id:
        return
    channel = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds[0].channels,name="genral")
    member_id = member.id
    response = f"Welcome to For Testing,<@{member_id}> !"
    await channel.send(response)


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    Keywords = ["sup","lol","yeet"]
    channel = message.channel
    for keyword in Keywords:
        if keyword.lower() in message.content.lower():
            user_id = message.author.id
            response = f"Did someone say {keyword.lower()}? I guess it was <@{user_id}>"
    await channel.send(response)

@bot.event
async def reminder():
    while(True):
        await bot.wait_until_ready()
        online_members = []
        for member in bot.get_all_members():
            online_members.append(member.id)
        if len(online_members) > 0:
            user = random.choice(online_members)
            channel = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds[0].channels,name="genral")
            response = f"So what are u up to <@{user.id}>"
            await channel.send(response)

        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
bot.loop.create_task(reminder())

real_token = "THE TOKEN"

bot.run("THE TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your script as a file with the file extension .py and then run it through your file manager (e.g. double-click the file in Windows). That should run your script without needing the shell open.

https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/#how-to-run-python-scripts-from-a-file-manager

Comment: nooo i wanted my bot to run even if my code has only run once . Like suppose I made a change in the code  so i run the code once using the shell then even if i close the shell the bot should still do as programmed. I needed to know that can that be done ? if yes then pls tell how

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use pythonw.exe in order to run a python script as a background process:

Python scripts (files with the extension .py) will be executed by python.exe by default. This executable opens a terminal, which stays open even if the program uses a GUI. If you do not want this to happen, use the extension .pyw which will cause the script to be executed by pythonw.exe by default (both executables are located in the top-level of your Python installation directory). This suppresses the terminal window on startup.

For example,

```
C:\ThanosDodd\Python3.6\pythonw.exe C:\\Python\Scripts\moveDLs.py
```

or

```
pythonw.exe pythonFile.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export code onto repl.it and make one more file called keep_alive.py

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return "Your bot is alive!"

def run():
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=<any Port>)

def keep_alive():
    server = Thread(target=run)
    server.start()
```

then do

```
from keep_alive import keep_alive
```

then call the keep_alive function before bot.run
this makes a flask server then u can  take the server link and make a monitor in http://uptimerobot.com/
For more info check the link
https://repl.it/talk/learn/Hosting-discordpy-bots-with-replit/11008